# Waiting to get a response from a function before using it in a line below?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on something in an older version of Node (8.x), and I wrote a function that counts values from a bunch of hashes in redis.

The problem is, the code always uses the default value of 0, because the function seems to run after its being used in the lines below it. I can see in my logs that the value returned from the function is not 0.

How can I ensure the function runs before it moves on and is used in the redis commands below it?

Thanks, sorry if this is a rookie qestion:

You can see below i'm defining blockEffort = 0. I then call the function below to get the real values. but by the time blockEffort is used in "redisCommands.push(['sadd', coin + ':blocksExplorer', [dateNow, shareData.height, shareData.blockHash, shareData.worker, blockEffort].join(':')]);" it's still zero.

```
if (isValidBlock) {
            var blockEffort = parseFloat(0);
            this.getCurrentRoundShares(function (roundShares) {
                    logger.debug("calling GetCurrentRoundShares");
                    blockEffort = [roundShares / shareData.blockDiff];
                    logger.debug(`{"message": "Calculating Block Effort", "totalRoundShares": "${roundShares}", "blockEffort": "${blockEffort}"}`);
                });
            redisCommands.push(['rename', coin + ':shares:roundCurrent', coin + ':shares:round' + shareData.height]);
            redisCommands.push(['rename', coin + ':shares:timesCurrent', coin + ':shares:times' + shareData.height]);
            redisCommands.push(['sadd', coin + ':blocksPending', [shareData.blockHash, shareData.txHash, shareData.height].join(':')]);
            redisCommands.push(['sadd', coin + ':blocksExplorer', [dateNow, shareData.height, shareData.blockHash, shareData.worker, blockEffort].join(':')]);
            redisCommands.push(['zadd', coin + ':lastBlock', dateNow / 1000 | 0, [shareData.blockHash, shareData.txHash, shareData.worker, shareData.height, dateNow].join(':')]);
            redisCommands.push(['zadd', coin + ':lastBlockTime', dateNow / 1000 | 0, [dateNow].join(':')]);
            redisCommands.push(['hincrby', coin + ':stats', 'validBlocks', 1]);
            redisCommands.push(['hincrby', coin + ':blocksFound', shareData.worker, 1]);
}



this.getCurrentRoundShares = function(cback) {
        
        connection.hgetall('ravencoin:shares:roundCurrent', function(error,result) {
            if (error) {
                logger.error(`{"message": "Error getCurrentRoundShares", "data": "${error}"}`);
                cback(error);
                return;
            } else {
                logger.debug(`{"message": "Calculating all shares in current round"}`);
                logger.debug(result.toString());

                var _shareTotal = parseFloat(0);
                for (var worker in result) {
                    logger.debug(`{"message": "Shares for each Worker", "worker": "${worker}", "shares": "${parseFloat(result[worker])}"} }`);
                    _shareTotal += parseFloat(result[worker]);
                }
                logger.debug("Total Shares: " + _shareTotal );
                cback(_shareTotal);
            }
        });         
        },
        function(err) {
              if (err) {
                logger.error(`{"message": "Error getCurrentRoundShares", "data": "${err}"}`);
                cback(0);
                return;
            }
    };
```

The full file is here: https://github.com/devdevdevdev1/rvnpool/blob/main/shareProcessor.js

Comment: You can't tell Javascript to wait for an asynchronous callback to execute.  So, you either put the remaining code INSIDE the callback (thus execution continues when the callback is called) or you switch to using promise interfaces for all asynchronous operations so you can use `await` on the function calls.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of using promises, but I don't think the version of node i'm on supports them fully. I guess i'll give it a try with all the code inside the callback.

Comment: You seriously need to advance beyond node version 8 - that is no longer even supported for bug or security fixes so it can be downright unsafe to use it.  Everything you show in this code looks like you need redis support for promises and doesn't look like you'd be missing anything from nodejs.  FYI, end of life for node version 8 was 2019-12-31.  So, it's been expired and unsupported for over two years now.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware. This is a fork of some mining pool software that will take a lot of untangling to get to more modern versions of node. It's certainly on the backlog list.

It does look like it supports promises, I implemented the one suggested below, but still having some problems with the order of execution...

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `this.getCurrentRoundShares` function return a `Promise`.

```
this.getCurrentRoundShares = function(cback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // do your stuf..
        
        let processHasFinishedSuccessfully = true;
        // if your stuff failed
        if (processHasFinishedSuccessfully){
           resolve();
        }
        else {
           reject(Error('Failed'));
        }
    };
```

Then, in your `this.handleShare` function, you await for the response

```
this.handleShare = async function(isValidShare, isValidBlock, shareData) {
    // your stuff ...

            await this.getCurrentRoundShares(function (roundShares) {
                    logger.debug("calling GetCurrentRoundShares");
                    blockEffort = parseFloat([roundShares / shareData.blockDiff]);
                    logger.debug(`{"message": "Calculating Block Effort", "totalRoundShares": "${roundShares}", "blockEffort": "${blockEffort}"}`);
                });

    // your stuff...
    };
```

This should ensure that the code execution does not proceed further until you get a response from the `getCurrentRoundShares ()` function.

Comment: Thank you, Do promises like this work in Node 8.x? I thought that wasn't the case.

Comment: As far as I am aware, yes.  Here are some links:

http://peterforgacs.github.io/2017/05/29/How-to-use-async-await-with-Node-js-8-0-0/
https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/

Comment: OK, so the promise did work, but it still inserted it to redis as 0 (logs say it should have been 154.727. I updated the code here (https://github.com/devdevdevdev1/rvnpool/blob/main/shareProcessor_promise.js) - any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What value does `roundShares ` have when you invoke the callback? There could be a handful of causes: failed parsing, the value is actually 0 etc.

Comment: The debug log on line 70 returns : "result": {"message": "Calculating Block Effort", "totalRoundShares": "30.7", "blockEffort": "154.7279059625679"}}

So the value isn't zero for sure. It still seems like it's taking the default when blockEffort is initialized.

Comment: I see. What values does `blockEffort` have if you log it immediately after awaiting the response on the `getCurrentRoundShares ()` ?

Comment: I actually put a log immediately after await this.getCurrentRoundShares, before the redisCommands where it's used and also after, and its 0 all 3 places. In the log is also shows up before any of the other logs inside getCurrentRoundShares, so that makes me believe it's still being executed before the function is complete.

Log: https://github.com/devdevdevdev1/rvnpool/blob/main/log_roundshares.PNG

Comment: Also interestingly, I was able to get the values into the redis command array if i move all those redisCommands into the await block under where blockEffort is set, however even though the commands are correct and the logger says "Sent all data to redis", it doesnt actually inset it into redis. No idea why, maybe because its using .exec? Also not sure if its wise to move those redisCommands statements into the await block either...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this [redis module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis), then it already has promise support built-in and you can use that directly.  You don't show the calling code, but if you make the calling function `async`, you can do this:

```
async function someFunction() {

    // ... other code here

    if (isValidBlock) {
        try {
            var blockEffort = parseFloat(0);
            let roundShares = await this.getCurrentRoundShares();
            logger.debug("calling GetCurrentRoundShares");
            blockEffort = [roundShares / shareData.blockDiff];
            logger.debug(`{"message": "Calculating Block Effort", "totalRoundShares": "${roundShares}", "blockEffort": "${blockEffort}"}`);
            redisCommands.push(['rename', coin + ':shares:roundCurrent', coin + ':shares:round' + shareData.height]);
            redisCommands.push(['rename', coin + ':shares:timesCurrent', coin + ':shares:times' + shareData.height]);
            redisCommands.push(['sadd', coin + ':blocksPending', [shareData.blockHash, shareData.txHash, shareData.height].join(':')]);
            redisCommands.push(['sadd', coin + ':blocksExplorer', [dateNow, shareData.height, shareData.blockHash, shareData.worker, blockEffort].join(':')]);
            redisCommands.push(['zadd', coin + ':lastBlock', dateNow / 1000 | 0, [shareData.blockHash, shareData.txHash, shareData.worker, shareData.height, dateNow].join(':')]);
            redisCommands.push(['zadd', coin + ':lastBlockTime', dateNow / 1000 | 0, [dateNow].join(':')]);
            redisCommands.push(['hincrby', coin + ':stats', 'validBlocks', 1]);
            redisCommands.push(['hincrby', coin + ':blocksFound', shareData.worker, 1]);
        } catch(e) {
            logger.debug(e);
            // handle error in this.getCurrentRoundShares() here
        }
    }
}

this.getCurrentRoundShares = async function() {
    let result = await connection.hGetAll('ravencoin:shares:roundCurrent');
    logger.debug(`{"message": "Calculating all shares in current round"}`);
    logger.debug(result.toString());

    let _shareTotal = parseFloat(0);
    for (var worker in result) {
        logger.debug(
            `{"message": "Shares for each Worker", "worker": "${worker}", "shares": "${parseFloat(result[worker])}"} }`
            );
        _shareTotal += parseFloat(result[worker]);
    }
    logger.debug("Total Shares: " + _shareTotal);
    return _shareTotal;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. This appears to be executing in the right order, but my query is no longer returning data. I had to change your hGetAll (that's not a function of redis) to let result = await connection.hgetall('ravencoin:shares:roundCurrent');, but "result" is now returning "true" instead of the data.

Comment: @DEVDEVDEVDEV - If you're using [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) to access redis, then [the doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis#redis-commands) says it supports `await client.hGetAll()`.  Perhaps you're using a different library.  Anyway, if this helped you get it figured out, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.

Comment: I am using that library, v2.8.0. Could be newer. The problem is the code you put above is not returning the query results into "result", its just returning "true".